# @SerializedName Ignored

Tags: java, gson, google-cloud-endpoints

My Google cloud endpoint receives an object in post body and when converting the JSON to actual Java object most of the fields are left empty. It seems that the endpoint API does not take into account gson annotations like @SerializedName

```
public class MyObject{

    @SerializedName("production_unit_ID")
    private Long productionUnitId;
    ...
    getters / setters

}
```

API:

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "puMyObject", httpMethod = "put", path = "putMyObject")
        public MyObject putWorkOrder(HttpServletRequest req, MyObject myobj) {

        myobj.getProductionUnitId(); // <-- null
```

In my pom.xml I have added the following dependencies as required by the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/app-engine

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints doesn't use GSON under the hood. Use [`ApiResourceProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/ApiResourceProperty) for this instead.